# it's hard to accept the truth because the lies sound so much better

Tags: word-usage

One of my friends (not a native English speaker) told me this is a famous saying

> "it's hard to accept the truth because the lies sound so much better"

I doubt it is. So, I googled a bit and got some hits. None of them appear to be it is a famous saying.

Could you give us some examples of the contexts?

Answer (score 1):

So it's not said by a famous person as far as I know, but a lot of people like it.

In context;

> "She has stayed with him and all his lies because "it's hard to accept
>   the truth because the lies sound so much better".

So, the way that sounds to me is;

The girl was in a not healthy relationship because her boyfriend lied to her a lot.

She stayed because she convinced herself he was telling the truth because facing reality, let's say he didn't care about her, would hurt her more than facing the truth. At least in her mind.

Another example could be;

> "The girl convinced herself her grandmother loved her because it's
>   hard to accept the truth and the lies she told herself sounded so much
>   better"

While this one has changed some things like the tenses, it means the same thing.